# Basic Angular (Binding not showing up)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I have the following directory:

```
-flapper-news
  -app.js
  -index.html
```

In app.js I have:

```
angular.module('flapperNews', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope',
function($scope){
  $scope.test = 'Hello world!';
}]);
```

In index.html.I have the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App!</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="flappeNews" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
      {{test}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I navigate to my index.html and I open it on google chrome only see the binding like so:

```
{{test}}
```

obviously not working. In my browser console I see:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/$injector/modulerr?p0=flappeNews&p1=Erro…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.19%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A139)
```

I have tried changing version of angular and including ngroute in my angular module but nothing works. Any idea of what is happening?

Comment: `typo` @ `flapperNews`...Missing `r` in `ng-app` directive..[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/wesvsr6c/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `ng-app="flappeNews"` instead of `ng-app="flapperNews"` on your body.

```
<body ng-app="flapperNews" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it is working :

use `ng-app="flapperNews"` instead of `ng-app="flappeNews"`

Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/84P1zpbHdhGOwI2oNMrQ?p=preview